# Put flags on OHLC chart in highstocks

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to put some flags on OHLC charts, same as done on line chart in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/flags-general/) example.

I've made a series object:

```
series : [
        {
            name : ticker,
            type: 'candlestick',
            data : chartData,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        },
        {
            type : 'flags',
            data : markersData,
            onSeries : 'dataseries',
            shape : 'circlepin',
            width : 16
        }
    ]
```

Here is what I get - chart is not being drawn at all. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Z96J/1/)

**How do I put flags on OHLC chart?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add flags to OHLC the same way you add them to any other type of chart.

The problem with your chart is that none of the dates provided in your parsed JSON are treated as dates, since they are just strings in the format `"2014-08-04T15:00:00.000Z"`. You need to provide Highstock with dates in the form of timestamps in milliseconds.

You can either change the JSON you receieve to provide this, or do it in post-processing like this:

```
for(i in chartData.data) {
    chartData.data[i][0] = new Date(chartData.data[i][0]).getTime();
}

for(i in markersData.data) {
    markersData.data[i].x = new Date(markersData.data[i].x).getTime();
}
```

As in [this updated JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/3Z96J/2/). The `Date` object parses the string and the `getTime` function return the timestamp in milliseconds.

I may also add that the flags are not on the series as you are not providing a ID for the series in your `chartData` JSON.

Comment: Another problem - flags are draw below the chart. Do you know how to fix? http://jsfiddle.net/3Z96J/3/

Comment: That is what I wrote in the last sentance of my answer. Your series must have an ID that is equal to the onSeries ID. `"id":"dataseries"` and `"onSeries":"dataseries"`.